# How to get Text file values into an Invoke-VMScript command?

Tags: powershell, powercli

I am trying to create OU's within an newly created DC using Invoke-VMScript but I cannot get the OU values from a text file to push through to the VM. I also am not sure where to perform the breaks in the multiline script so it passes through to the VM correctly.

Sample of OU File:

```
Adm_Apps
Adm_Apps/Groups
Adm_Apps/Users
Adm_Apps/Users/Human Users
Adm_Apps/Users/Human Users/Internal
Adm_Apps/Users/Human Users/External
Adm_Apps/Users/Non-Human Users
Adm_Apps/Users/Non-Human Users/Internal
Adm_Apps/Users/Non-Human Users/External
```

Than the Script I am using:

```
$OUStructure = Get-Content "C:\Users\admr_mornevr\Documents\PowerShell\OdekSpace\Active Directory\OUs\OdekOUStructure.txt"

$CreateOUs = "`$MyDomain = Get-ADDomain | Select DistinguishedName;
`$connectionString = 'LDAP://' + `$MyDomain.DistinguishedName;
`$objDomain  = [ADSI]`$connectionString;

$OUStructure | Foreach-Object {
  `$domain = `$MyDomain.DistinguishedName
  `$newOU = ''
  `$ous = (Split-Path `$_ -Parent).Split('\')
  [array]::Reverse(`$ous)
  `$ous | Foreach-Object {
    if (`$_.Length -eq 0) {
      return
    }
    `$newOU = `$newOU + ',OU=' + `$_
  }
  `$nyOUNavn = Split-Path `$_ -Leaf
  `$newOU = 'OU=' + `$nyOUNavn + `$newOU

  `$objOU = `$objDomain.Create('OrganizationalUnit', `$newOU)
  `$objOU.SetInfo()
}"
Invoke-VMScript -ScriptType PowerShell -ScriptText $CreateOUs -VM $DCName -GuestCredentials $DomainCredential
```

I have modified the above code as follows:

```
$OUs = Import-Csv 'Path to CSV File'

$CreateOUs = "foreach ($OU in $OUs)
{
`$Name = `$(`$OU.Name)
`$Path = `$(`$OU.Path)
New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name `$Name -Path `$Path
}"
Invoke-VMScript -ScriptType PowerShell -ScriptText $CreateOUs -VM $DCName -GuestCredentials $DomainCredential
```

Comment: Can't you use a [Here-String](https://powershell.org/2019/04/hear-hear-for-here-strings/) so you don't have to use backticks?

Comment: Please could you edit your question and put the modified code in there as formatted text. In a comment, code is hardly readable.

Comment: The issue seems to be with passing the content of the $OUs variable into the Invoke-VMScript -Scriptext command

Comment: @Theo My struggle is to get the $OUs variable content into the $CreateOUs command so it can be passed to the VM using Invoke-VMScript command. I am sure I am being an idiot and is missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to @Theo for pointing me in the right direction as well as LucD over on VMware Communities. The below code is what worked for me.

```
$OUs = Import-Csv 'C:\PathtoFile.csv' 

$CreateOUs = @'
New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name $($Name) -Path $($Path)
'@

foreach ($OU in $OUs)
{
$Name = $($OU.Name)
$Path = $($OU.Path)
$ExecuteCmd = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($CreateOUs) 
Invoke-VMScript -ScriptType Powershell -ScriptText $ExecuteCmd -VM $DCName -GuestCredential $DomainCredential
}
```